# Vuetify align list to right side of parent card

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and Vuetify, but I'm trying to place a search bar inside of a v-card, but have it be aligned to the right side of the card. The card itself spans the entire page (minus padding) but I'd like the search bar to be a fixed width and located on the right side of the card. I was able to set the width of the list, but I have been unable to find an answer as to how I might position the search bar on the right side of the card.

```
<v-card>
    <v-card-title>Card Title</v-card-title>
    <v-list width="500">
        <v-list-item>
            <v-text-field
                v-model="search"
                append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Search"
                single-line
                hide-details
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by adding the *flex* attribute on the v-card and then justifying the v-list-item to the *end*. So it looks like this:

```
<v-card class="d-flex-column">
    <v-card-title>Card Title/v-card-title>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-item class="d-flex justify-end mt-n9">
            <v-text-field
                v-model="search"
                append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Search"
                single-line
                hide-details
                class="shrink"
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
</v-card>
```